# compute x-component of vector in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm sure this is a really basic question, but I've googled and haven't found it. Supposed I have a vector in sympy

```
z = 3*x + 4*y
```

How do I compute the x-component of the vector (i.e. the 3)? z/x doesn't give it (there's still the y-part), nor does z[x] or z.x. Surely there's a way to do this, right?

Comment: Okay, z.subs({x:1,y:0}) works. Is there a better way??

Comment: I wouldn't expect vector support when your variable `z` is simply an expression of variables `x, y`. Perhaps make your variable a function `z(x, y)` and then do `z(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> z = 3*x + 4*y
>>> z.coeff(x)
3
```

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner. I knew there was something like this. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think that calling this expression a vector is somewhat incorrect. Indeed, if you keep in your mind the assumption that `x` and `y` are some base vectors, it will work *in your mind*. However the library will not provide any vector-like functionality because it does not know that you want to treat this as vectors.

For vector with all the nice helper methods you can use the `diffgeom` submodule of sympy which provides predefined `R^2` and `R^3` spaces with numerous coordinate systems.

However, for your case *pattern matching* seems a much more natural choice. After all pattern matching is one of the basic building blocks of CASes like Mathematica and others.

In SymPy as in all other CASes you work with symbolic expressions which are basically big trees with operators at each node and some symbols at the leafs. You can match trees against some predefined patterns much in the same way in which you can use regex on strings. In sympy you use `Wild` to do that:

```
x, y = Symbols("x y")
a, b = Wild('a', exclude=[x, y]), Wild('b', exclude=[x, y])
(2*x + 3*y).match(a*x + b*y)
```

For the special case of linear combinations check `coeff` which is described in the other answer.

See: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Idioms-and-Antipatterns#wild-and-match